# How to delete attachments associated with custom field type when post property changes?

Tags: custom-field, images, attachments, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site with cars that have a custom field named "deal type". That field can be either "selling" or "sold".

The "selling" cars have a custom field named "main picture", with a single picture attached to it, and another named "gallery", with multiple car photos as attachments.

When the site admin changes a "selling" car to "sold", I need to delete all those attachments associated with the gallery, in order to save space (but I must keep the attachment added in the "main picture" field).

Is there any hook to detect that the custom field "deal type" has changed to "sold" and trigger the deletion of all the attachments associated with the "gallery" custom field?

Additional information: I use the Advanced Custom Fields Pro version to create the custom fields.

Comment: Sorry, but advanced custom fields (as you read in the [faq]) is like every other 3rd party code not on topic for this network site. You might want to try their support – or get a better plugin instead. _ACF_ saves meta data in _very_ strange way (with unnecessary reference fields) and pollutes your DB in no time.

Comment: Well, I mentioned I was using ACF in case that would help anyone, but the question would be the same to any other plugin or even without a plugin, all I wanted to know was how to delete a certain subset of post attachments when the post is saved with a specific value for one of its fields. Anyway, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `save_post` hook.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mytheme_my_post_just_updated' );

function mytheme_my_post_just_updated($post_id){

    $deal_type = get_field($post_id, 'deal_type');

    if($deal_type == 'sold'){

       $gallery = get_field($post_id, 'gallery');// This bit and the next few lines will depend on how you've set up the custom field. 

        // Fast forward a few lines...
        foreach($images as $image){ // I'm assuming that $images is an array of attachment_ids, but will depend on how you've used ACF to create the custom field
            wp_delete_attachment($image, true); // args are attachment_id and whether or not to bypass trash.
        }

    }

}
```

Put the above code into your theme's `functions.php`.

More on `wp_delete_attachment()` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment

Comment: You might want to use `apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_data', $data, $postarr );` instead, which triggers for all post types – except attachments – on update.